# DataTable.Load() not getting data from ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sqlite, mono

I am working with SQLite in Unity and am having issues loading data from a table I have which is generated by the game at the start screen. I don't get any errors and my the "reader.HasRows" call does come back true. However, when I try to load the data into a DataTable I get nothing. I have used SQLite with C# before and am using that code for reference but I have never had any issues like this before.

ScoreControl.cs:

```
using (SqliteConnection dbCon = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + Application.dataPath + "MainScoreDB.sqlite3"))
{
    if (dbCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        dbCon.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM highscores";

    SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(query, dbCon);
    SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        Scores.Load(reader);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No Data was Returned");
    }


    if (dbCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        dbCon.Close();
}
```

The else statement is never fired so reader definitely gets something. I am at a loss here, I have tried multiple formats of database (s3db, sqlite, sqlite3) but all have the same outcome. I also get no errors.

*EDIT*

The Application.dataPath refers to the root project folder, I use it to generate the database and the table, as well as referencing it so I know that it is querying the right database, I have also made a database without the table in it and got an error, so I know it is accessing the database.

Scores.Load() is a method in the DataTable it loads enters the data returned from the reader.

So it would appear the while loop is going through the right amount of times, however it isn't returning anything. Do I need to manage the type of data coming out of the database at all?

Comment: What is the value for Application.dataPath? Did you check if you are querying the correct database?

Comment: When combining a path with a filename, use Path.Combine(). It will take care of any [potentially missing] backslashes.

Comment: I think we need to see your Scores.Load method, because others seems fine here. Also, what do you see when you debug if statement? You could easily peek the rows, which would make you sure if you fetch the records correctly.

Comment: as a side note, you're wrapping in a `using` so you don't need to put `dbCon.Close()` - this will happen automatically; also don't need the check at the start - it won't be open.

Comment: I assume that Scores is a DataTable and thus Scores.Load(reader) loads the datatable using the reader....

Comment: You may be getting a 'New Row' for inserts, but which is currently empty.  I remember years ago running into this with a data table or something.  There was a property to turn off getting the new row back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to call Read on your datareader.  The cursor is at the begining before reading the first row.  Try doing a while loop to go through all the rows as a Reader is a forward moving only object.

```
 if (reader.HasRows)  
 {    
    while (reader.Read())    
    { 
         // Load each row 1 at a time here    
    }  
 }
```

Reference:

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader~HasRows.html

EDIT

Give the data adapter a try and see if it behaves better or gives you another clue to what is wrong.

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(dbCommand);
da.Fill(scores);
```

Comment: Just tried this, it went through the loop once and then returned nothing, there are 3 entries in the table.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint and inspected what data is in the reader while you loop?  For instance is the first loop a valid row?

Comment: Also, Instead of doing a datareader you can switch to a dataadapter and that will support a Load function.

Comment: The loop is not a valid row, I am looking into it potentially being an empty insert row as you mentioned in the above comment

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem,

Except mine was that for some reason the DataTable simply wasn't receiving all the rows it was owed.

The proper way to fill a DataTable for SqlLite seems to be:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
cnn.Open();
SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
mycommand.CommandText = sql;
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(mycommand);
adapter.Fill(dt);
cnn.Close();
```